# AWS nodejs and dynmodb connection in Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-dynamodb

I am having problems connecting to a DynamoDB Database from AWS Elasticbeanstalk. I just created a new project inside of elasticbeanstalk using the newest amazon linux ami and node js configuration. I then went and created a a new dynamodb table in the same region. I know want the instance which was created for me to be able to connect to the dynamodb instance I just created (I have a basic insert and get code written in javascript to test the connection). All of this setup so far has been through the console. I then started to read this doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-environment-resources-dynamodb.html which shows how to connect elastic beanstalk and dynamodb together (this example shows php), but it is not very thorough. It seems to the first step is to create the code which I have and the second step is to create a table which I have, but again I used the console to do this. Then they state there needs to be a .ebextensions/options.config but don't state how or where to put this. As well, don't I need to enter my credentials somewhere? Has anyone connected elasticbeanstalk and dynamodb together that can provide a step by step "idiot-proof" instruction how to do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

First off you will need to set your AWS credentials as environment variables. You can do this a number of ways but using a config file in the `.ebextensions` folder in the root of your application is quite easy to get going. The config files are parsed in alphabetical order so call you config file something like `01_env-vars.config`:

```
option_settings:
  - option_name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    value: [MYACCESSKEY]
  - option_name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    value: [MYACCESSSECRET]
```

You then have a choice between using the [aws-sdk](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) or a model abstraction over the top. My preferred option at the minute is to use the [vogels](https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels) module. This hides the *funky* typed api required to talk to dynamodb. The vogels docs are very good but here's a basic example of theirs of how to create models:

```
var BlogPost = vogels.define('BlogPost', {
  hashKey : 'email',
  rangeKey : ‘title’,
  schema : {
    email   : Joi.string().email(),
    title   : Joi.string(),
    content : Joi.binary(),
    tags   : vogels.types.stringSet(),
  }
});
```

You can then save a model like this:

```
BlogPost.create({
  email: 'werner@example.com', 
  title: 'Expanding the Cloud', 
  content: 'Today, we are excited to announce the limited preview...'
}, function (err, post) {
  console.log('created blog post', post.get('title'));
});
```

Comment: THANKS! One question. I have been testing locally against dynamodb local so I connected like this in my code: var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-west-2",
    endpoint: "http://localhost:8000",
    credentials: new AWS.Credentials('whatever', 'whatever', sessionToken = null)
});. Do I know then need to change the region, endpoint, and credentials. If so, how do I get credentials I added in the .config file to be read in my code?